# Multiknapsack algorithm - out of collection while trying to remove object

Tags: c#, algorithm

I've encountered the problem while working on my multiknapsack solver.
The program is working well on one knapsack but when it comes to multiple knaps there are some problems.

Problem: The items aren't removed from collection. I know that I need to do this, because for the second knapsack its iterating again through the same objects - so the maximized val is the same...

```
private void Knapsack()
{
    List<Plecak> descendingKanps = _plecakList.OrderByDescending(o => o.W).ToList(); // List of configured Kanpsacks in descending order
    List<Produkt> descendingProducts = _produktList.OrderByDescending(o => o.cena).ToList(); // List of products to pack in descending order
    int N = descendingProducts.Count; //number of items in product list
    double maxVal = 0; // accumulated value of one knapsack
    foreach (Plecak p in descendingKanps) // for every knapsack...
    {
        double[,] V = new double[N + 1, (int)p.W + 1]; //array that stores best option (the value of item)
        for (int c = 0; c <= p.W; c++) //since its a 0-1 MKP problem so initialize whole array with zeroes
        {
            V[0, c] = 0;
        }
        for (int r = 0; r <= N; r++)
        {
            V[r, 0] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) // constraint of items count
        {
            for (int wt = 1; wt <= p.W; wt++) //the constraint of weight
            {
                if (descendingProducts[i - 1].waga < wt + 1) // if weight of the product is less than constraint, so it can be added...
                    V[i, wt] = Math.Max(descendingProducts[i - 1].cena + V[i - 1, wt - descendingProducts[i - 1].waga], V[i - 1, wt]); // find best solution and add the value to the Value array, comapre the value with the value form previous row
                else
                    V[i, wt] = V[i - 1, wt]; // keep 0, or last best solution

                maxVal = V[i, wt]; // assign to variable
            }
        }
        summary.Items.Add("maximum val for knapsack: " + p.nazwa + " is: " + maxVal); // print out the value of knapsack
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be nice to know the purpose of the code. Can you insert comments explaining what everything does? Like setting the top row's and the first column's values to 0 in the 'V' array (at beginning of foreach-loop)? What confuses me the most is the three for-loops in the bottom half.

Comment: I am sorry but I still dont understand the code. I can't seem to understand the the logic. How am i supposed to understand this?

Comment: PS. It looks like to me in the third for-loop (with 'int wt'), that 'maxVal' is assigned to a number without purpose everytime the loop runs. 'maxVal' isn't used anywhere else before the end. And what is 'cena' and 'waga' and 'nazwa'.

Comment: it is used to print the result. About the logic, i think you should check some books about knapsack problem, there is all you need to know

Answer (score 0):

This will hopefully turn into an answer, but for now it is a question.

In your code you have this:

```
for (int c = 0; c <= p.W; c++) //since its a 0-1 MKP problem so initialize whole array with zeroes
{
    V[0, c] = 0;
}
for (int r = 0; r <= N; r++)
{
     V[r, 0] = 0;
}
```

You say that you "*initialize whole array with zeroes*". The above code will do this to an array:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
```

You'll only ever reach the first column and the top row. If all places in the array should be changed to `0`, then this is the correct approach:

```
for (int r = 0; r <= N; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c <= p.W; c++) 
    {
        V[r, c] = 0;
    }
}
```

I hope this input can be of help.